# Reroute Express dynamically via next()

Tags: node.js, express

Does anybody know how to reroute a call dynamically in Express (Node.js)? My route conditionally diverges at some point and I would like to change the "next()" parameter somehow to do that.

For example, let's say I have the following routes:
**route1 = func1, func2, func3**

**route2= func4, func5**

I'd like the following flow to occur:
**func1 => func2 (reroute to route2 if Android) => func4 => func5

func1 => func2 (don't reroute if iOS) => func3**

I considered res.redirect(/route2), but I'd like the reroute to occur internally without the client-side knowing about it.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks!
Henri

Comment: Just put your route handling code in independent functions and use `if` logic to call the desired functions.  You don't have to tell the client to redirect.  You can just directly call the functions you want to execute.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That's kind of what I ended up doing, but I wanted to use existing functions that are used by other routes with the function(req,res,next) signatures. I ended up using async.waterfall which allowed me to reuse those functions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using async.waterfall to address my issue in a rather clean way. For those running into the same problem and wanting to reuse existing functions used by other routes, you can use async.waterfall and use "cb" for the "next" parameter as such:

```
 conditionalReroute: function(req, res, next) {

      if(someCondition) {
        async.waterfall([
                         function(cb){route1.someFunction(req, res, cb); }, 
                         function(cb){ route2.someOtherFunction(req, res, cb); }, 
                         function(cb){ route1.soomeFunction2(req, res, cb); }, 
                         }
                    ]);

      } else {
          next();
      } 
}
```